# Magento - place an order for a given customer by the administrator in frontend

Tags: magento

Would it be possible, with way or another, to give the possibility to the Magento administrator to place orders for a given customer within from the frontend?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Talking about by admin area you want to create an order?

Comment: The order have to be placed by an administrator, but in the frontend, like all the other customers.

He have to select from the list of customers, and then place an order for the selected one.

Thanks.

Comment: There's an extension with POS in its name. You login with admin username but it's all on the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through Magento admin area...

1) sales->order->create new order

2) you will get all the email of all your customers..select email of any customer and place any order.

3) you will get option to select products, add shipping charge and more...

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll make with this solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do that on frontend : 
I don't think it's easily feasible : as you may know, the checkout process rely a lot on session, and it also fetch user data from the session.
It may be feasible, however, ifd you get customer data with a custom controller which retrieve data for instance in json. I don't know how to make customer data retrieving secure since you probably can't be logged in...
After that, well, good luck to prepopulate the forms in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this, you can build a feature to log in as a customer, which is granted only to admin users who already have all of the customer's data. You'll probably still hit a snag when it comes to payment time for the order, though. If you do this, make sure to spend significant time securing the "login as" module and allowing only authorized adminitrators.

Answer (score 1):

This was not available when you first posted this, but now there is a free extension "[Login as Customer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer.html)" that I have found to be easy, intuitive and incredibly useful in order to place orders for customers from the front end instead of the back end. When you have a heavily customized site with non-standard product configurations or option dependencies, it is sometimes not a realistic option to place orders from the back end. This extension works beautifully.